# Firestore: Best practice for check Post Like-reaction from a user

Tags: firebase, react-native

Firestore costs are based in read, write, and delete. So i'm dealing with this dilemma. How can i structure Firestore database for check user likes in each post.

I know that i can structure like this:

```
Document:
        Post:
            Likes:
                 {user_id1, user_id2...}
```

But the problem is that what happen is my app becomes popular and a post turns viral and get 1million likes. Firestore document maximum size is 1mb, so won't handle 1 million string information.

Obviously i can make  a function checkIfLiked(postId, userId) but would be very expensive is app becomes popular.

Is there other way to handle this?. Taking in account costs and pricing

Comment: Not an answer, but a good reference where to find more details in a specific use case here: https://youtu.be/haMOUb3KVSo

Answer (score 2):

The only way to manage lists of data that could grow too large to store in a single document is to split each item of data into a document in a new collection.  It's customary to use a subcollection nested under the parent document.

Yes, it is going to cost more document reads than if you put each item in one document, but there is really not alternative. This is how Firestore is able to scale massively.  If you anticipate your app going viral, you should be prepared to pay the cost of the services to support that.